# Tricky sigma algebra/measurable set question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let 
>   $$ 
> X := \{ x = (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_k \in \{0,1\} \forall k \in \{1,\dots,n\}\}
> $$
>   and let for all $k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$
>   $$
> f_k : X \to \mathbb{R} \qquad \textrm{s.t.} \qquad
> f_k(x) = x_k
> $$
>   For each $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ describe explicitly the *smallest $\sigma$-algebra* $\mathcal{A}_j \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that all functionss $f_1, \dots, f_j$ are $\mathcal{A}_j$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable, i.e.:
>   $$
> \mathcal{A}_j := \bigcap_{\textrm{$\mathcal{A}$ is $\sigma$-alg. s.t. $f_1, \dots, f_j$ are $\mathcal{A}$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-meas.}} \mathcal{A}
> $$
>
> Show that $f_l$ is not $\mathcal{A}_j$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable when $l > j$.

Hi,  whilst revising for an exam, I have attempted this with no luck. I thought about considering the $n$ dimensional lattice and also a formula for the number of sets in the $\sigma$-algebra. Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

In general if $Y$ is a function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ such that $\{Y\in C\}=\Omega$ for some countable set $C$ then: $$\sigma(X):=\{\{X\in D\}\mid D\subseteq C\}$$

Consequently if $C$ is finite with $\{Y=c\}\neq\varnothing$ for every $c\in C$ then the cardinality of $\sigma(X)$ is $2^{|C|}$.

Comment: Could you please expand on this? Still unsure :)

Comment: The essence is that the $sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable that takes exactly $n$ distinct values will contain exactly $2^n$ events. Now compare those generated by $f_l$ and $f_j$. If $l>j$ then the first will have more events than the second so cannot be a subcollection of the second.